# Ao clicar em um botão, quero que minha box abra com uma transição

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Tenho uma box:

```
.box1 {
  width: 470px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fbfcee;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 333px;
  animation: help;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
```

E tenho uma maneira de abrir ela, a partir de um clique em um determinado botão:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box2").click(function(){
        $(".menusec").toggle();
    });
});
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fechar").click(function(){
        $(".menusec").hide('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

O HTML Do botão que quando clico nele, aparece minha box:

```
<div class="menusec" style="display: none;"></div> 


<div class="row">
    <div class="box1">
         <a href="#" class="box2">EM QUE POSSO AJUDAR?</a>
    </div>
         <span class="fechar">X</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Queria saber como fazer para que quando eu clicasse no botão, minha box abrisse mas não grotescamente, vai instantaneamente, queria colocar uns 2 segundos de transição por exemplo, pra ela ir abrindo, e quando chegar 2 segundos chegar até a escala total. Aguardo resposta, grato!

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML também?

Comment: pode usar a função fadeIn() do jQuery

Comment: Obrigado, o fadeIn() ajudou!

Answer (score 0):

Adicionei a função `fadeIn()` e `fadeOut()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $(".box2").click(function(){
        $(".menusec").fadeIn("slow");
    });

  $(".fechar").click(function(){
        $(".menusec").fadeOut("slow");
    });
  
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 470px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fbfcee;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 333px;
  animation: help;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menusec" style="display: none;">oioioioioioi</div> 


<div class="row">
    <div class="box1">
         <a href="#" class="box2">EM QUE POSSO AJUDAR?</a>
    </div>
         <span class="fechar">X</span>
    </div>
</div>
```